# How do I tell a Rails 4 app where my SSL certs are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl

I'm trying to tell a Rails 4 app where to find the SSL certificates.

Ww got it working by modifying the `bin/rails`, adding this

```
if ENV['SSL'] == "true"
  module Rails
    class Server < ::Rack::Server
      def default_options
        super.merge({
          :Port => 443,
          :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
          :daemonize => false,
          :debugger => false,
          :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
          :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
          :SSLEnable => true,
          :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
          :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                           File.open("/path/to/my/private/.key").read),
          :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                           File.open("/path/to/my.cert").read),
          :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]],
        })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

all good but I want these setting in my `config/environments/staging.rb` file instead, and I want it to be non-specific to Webbrick.

1. Is this the right approach, and
2. if so, how do I move these settings into `config/environments/staging.rb`?

Comment: You should probably use a reverse proxy (nginx or apache) to decrypt SSL and decouple your app entirely from SSL certificates and keys.

Comment: As tpbowden said, you want to terminate your SSL connection using an nginx/apache reverse proxy.   In the 10+ years I've been building Rails apps, never once have I configured SSL directly in Rails.   Using something like passenger is probably your path of least resistance.

Comment: Okay went with Nginx — will also probably go with Unicorn over Webbrick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus from the comments is:

1. No, and
2. see 1.

Thanks @tpbowden and @josh-deeden for your quick responses.

Comment: Also, if you're deploying to Heroku, you might want to check out this handy tutorial: http://readysteadycode.com/howto-setup-ssl-with-rails-and-heroku